# Radix Sort integers using queues C++

Tags: c++, sorting, queue, radix-sort

I've been trying to solve this error in my algorithm (of 3 digit numbers) that is sorting only by the least significant digit (right most digit of the number) each pass of n digits. I'm trying to work from the right most digit, moving leftward. One of my attempted solutions was to work from left to right since it was sorting in reverse, though it improved the sort, it was still incorrect. Any assistance is much appreciated?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <ctime>
#define queueSize 10 
#define arraySize 50
#define numberOfDigits 3

int getTheDigit(int num, int count);

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

srand(time(NULL)); // random seed
int randomNumbers[arraySize], indexCount = 0; 
queue <int> sorter[queueSize];

// generating 3 digit random numbers
while(indexCount < arraySize) { randomNumbers[indexCount++] = rand() % 890 + 100; }

// printing all the unsorted random numbers
for(int count = 0; count < arraySize; count++){
    if(count %10 == 0) puts("");
    cout << randomNumbers[count] << " "; 
}
puts("\n");

int putbackCount = 0, whileCount = 0;

for(int outerCount = 0; outerCount < numberOfDigits; outerCount++){
    for(int count = 0; count < arraySize; count++){
        int theDigit = getTheDigit(randomNumbers[count], outerCount+1);
        printf("%d. number: %d Digit: %d\n", count+1, randomNumbers[count], theDigit); // debugging statement
        sorter[theDigit].push(randomNumbers[count]); 
    }   
    puts("");

        //dumping the stack back to the array for another pass
        while(whileCount < queueSize){
            if(whileCount % 10 == 0) puts("");
            while(!sorter[whileCount].empty()){
                randomNumbers[putbackCount++] = sorter[whileCount].front(); sorter[whileCount].pop();   
            }   
            whileCount++;
        }       
}
printf("\nSORTED ARRAY\n");

 for(int count = 0; count < arraySize; count++){
    if(count % 10 == 0) puts("");
    cout << randomNumbers[count] << " ";
 }
puts("\n");

return 0;
}

int getTheDigit(int num, int count){ 

switch(count){
    case 1: return num%10; break;
    case 2: return num/10%10; break;
    case 3: return num/100; break;
}
return (int)NULL;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `whileCount` becomes equal to `queueSize` on the first iteration of the big loop (with `outerCount  == 0`). On all subsequtent iterations, `dumping the stack back` step is not in fact executed.

Comment: What Igor Tandetnik is noting is that you need to set whileCount = 0; , just before the while loop: while(whileCount < queueSize){ ... . You also need to set putbackCount = 0; just before that same while.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ahhhh. I forgot to reset that conditional counter. Always gets me. Thanks!

Comment: @rcgldr I previously reinitialized putbackCount to 0 but never reinitialized whileCount to 0. Not sure what happened but I did as you and Igor suggested and all is well now! Thanks again!